# Windows 7 stuck on Boot Screen

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

My HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC stuck on Boot Screen. I got bellow result when test hard disk.

```
Hard Disk 1 Quick (303)
Hard Disk 1 Full (305)
```

[image: error_img]

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Is this a direct result of trying http://superuser.com/questions/859166/partition-a-hard-drive-without-losing-data ?

Comment: @Tetsujin No. This question hasn't any relationship with that one.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: the Master Boot Record has been corrupted (for shame). On another PC, make a recovery disk or USB drive with the appropriate OS (e.g. Ubuntu Linux, which is free, may be run from a CD or flash drive). If your PC boots from the rescue media, then you can try to fix the HDD problem, or just install the new OS and hope your data is still on the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

305 and 303 are usually an indication of [hard drive failure](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01443317), you would need to install a new hard drive and use your HP recovery discs to re-install Windows.

[image]

Comment: What kind of hard drive failure is that ? Complete dead of hard drive or bad sectors ? Is there any method to check that ?

Comment: Usually bad sectors, but could be a platter motor, controller failure also, it is a non specific error.

Comment: [I use Spinrite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm), not free but the best hard drive utility.